# R studio: Creating a pivot-like table of a subset of data from excel

Tags: r, statistics

- I have a very large excel spreadsheet I am hoping to analyze in R
- The spreadsheet has four columns: AGE, SEX, EMPLOYMENT STATUS, WAGES
- The table looks like this
  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYA8P.png)
  (Employed = 1-9, Unemployed = "blank cells")
- I want to output something like a pivot table that allows me to understand the average wages of people by Age and Sex, **but only the subset who are employed (excluding blanks in the employment column)**

I am a medical student and not very experienced with R! Appreciate any help!

Comment: Before other people downvote your questions, I would recommend you to read Chapter 5 of R4DS (http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html) and learn how to use tidyverse. Everything you described here should be as easy as a few line of codes after you read that chapter.

Comment: Take a look at the Janitor package which does try to do something like a pivot table.

Comment: @Hao: Base R answers would probably be pretty short. Tidyverse solutions are not universally shorter than base R. And to KIT:  Look at the base.functions: ‘tapply’ and ‘by’ when attempting to emulate pivot tables. Learn to use logical operation in the i-position of the ‘[‘ function for selection. Also make an attempt (and document it) when posting questions. Just b/c you’re a medical student should not absolve you from learning the rules here. (I’m a physician and needed to study the documentation. )

Answer (score 0):

With data.table:

```
# example data
N <- 25
df <- data.frame(
    age        = sample(18:65, N, TRUE),
    sex        = sample(1:2,   N, TRUE),
    employment = sample(1:10,  N, TRUE),
    wages      = sample(1:50,  N, TRUE)*10
)


# convert to data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# pivot
df[employment != "", .(avg_wages = mean(wages)), by=.(age, sex)]
```

To explain the 'pivot' part in English:

- Keep rows where 'employment' is not blank
- Create a new variable named 'avg_wages' that is the mean of 'wages'
- But where we take the mean of wages by 'age' and 'sex'

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I've got 5 minutes, so here's a quick solution.